# Access token for multiple pages in Facebook-Graph-Api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have some trouble with facebook graph api. From this question [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48707646/facebook-graph-api-190-this-method-must-be-called-with-a-page-access-token) I knew that fb team changed their api. I want to know how can I get access token for multiple pages?

Previously I used user token to get /insights metrics

Answer (score 1):

This is how you get Page Tokens for all your Pages:

`/me/accounts?fields=id,name,access_token`