# Getting a total posts and total engagements from the Facebook API for a page

Tags: php, facebook, api

I'm trying to get the total number of posts on a Facebook page in a given month and also the interactions with it (I have an API access token from the page owner).

I think the data I might need is stored under insights https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.1/insights but when trying to call the endpoint: `https://graph.facebook.com/114033751988338/insights/page_views_total?fields=user_access_token&access_token=******` as per the instructions on this SO post [Facebook Graph API (#190) This method must be called with a Page Access Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48707646/facebook-graph-api-190-this-method-must-be-called-with-a-page-access-token?rq=1#)

I'm getting the following error back:

`(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (user_access_token) on node type (Page)`.

So obviously the SO accepted answer is no longer relevant?

My question, how do I access the insights? Will insights even provide me with the data I'm after?

Comment: The field on the Page object is called `access_token`, not `user_access_token`.

Comment: number of posts: i believe there is no insights metric for this, you would have to grab the posts from the feed and count them on your own.